# How to get the dynamic height and width of table in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the height and width of table in bs4 . I have not assign any height and width to the table in the html I want the height and width of the table should be dynamic , is there a way to access height and width dynamically in bs4?

```
html = fancy_html(i)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
mydivs = soup.findAll("table")
```

when I am printing `mydivs` I am getting the table with values . **I want to access their height and width, I don't want to fix the height and width of the table**

Comment: Beautifulsoup does not render the HTML, the table has no height. The only thing you can access with bs is any value regarding the dimension set in HTML.

Comment: @KlausD is there a way to access height and width according to the elements inside the table , the elements can be changed so I need dynamic thats why

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic" width? The width of the table in pixel depends on the screen size. This is not a property BeautifulSoup has access to, because this is not encoded in the html of a website.